# box.com ssl certificate

Tags: ssl, curl, certificate, box-api

I'm trying to access box.com with libcurl. To use SSL I exported the SSL certificates with my web browser, box.com uses certificates issued by GeoTrust. But even if I pass them to curl (also with the command line tool (curl https://www.box.com --cacert /certs.pem)) I get an error that curl can't verify the certificate.

If I do exactly the same with a different site, which uses certificates issued by CAcert everything works just fine.

Do I need more/different certificates for box.com, additional to the GeoTrust certificates shown by the browser? If I use the complete certificate bundle stored in my system at /etc/ssl/certs I can connect to box.com but how do I found out which certificates are needed?

Comment: I also have this problem; none of the certs I tried worked for verification, so I ended up disabling it. Please be sure to update us if you figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to get it working, you could set this attribute to false:

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER
```